# Get text between symbols, regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a problem, i can't figure out a way to get out text between symbols.

```
site.com/hello-world/my-page-title/
```

i want to get my-page-title only? How?
Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will put "my-page-title" in the second group:

```
^([^/]*/){2}([^/]*)/$
```

If you always want the last group you can use:

```
^.*/([^/]*)/$
```

Comment: ^.*/ isn't necessary in the second regex.

Answer (score 1):

This regex always gives you the last URI segment in the first capturing group as long as the URI is terminated with a slash

```
.+/(.+)/
```

if the slash sometimes misses you can use

```
.+/(.+)/?
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i am not so good with regex, but title return null?

```
string url = /hello-world/my-page-text/    
string title = Regex.Match(url, @"^*./([^/])/$").Groups[1].Value;
```

it did work, the * was the error in the regex code

Comment: you need a + after [^/] otherwise it would only capture titles that are one character long, which is why you're getting null.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex or String.Split

```
        //Regex
        string s = "site.com/hello-world/my-page-title/";
        Match match = Regex.Match(s, "([^/]+)/$");
        string matchedString = match.Groups[1].Value;


        //Split
        string[] sections = s.Split(new char[]{'/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string lastSection = sections[sections.Length - 1];
```